# Memtest86 in Ubuntu 14.04 problem

Tags: 14.04, kernel, purge, memtest

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and I tried to update it (to the latest distribution) but I encountered an error. I don't quite remember the error message.

Reading tips from some forums, I moved on to cleaning the old kernels using the following method:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image 
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic
```

I purged nearly all of the listed old kernels. When there were about two left, the purge command ceased to work. There was no error message, simply nothing happened. The system didn't crash. I rebooted it and since then every time I try to start the system, Memtest86 v4.20 starts scanning.

No matter how long I let the Memtest test the memory (up to about 5 hours), Reboot always ends up the same way - Memtest starts it all over again. Despite the message:

```
*****Pass complete, no errors, press Esc to exit*****
```

Is the system dead?
Do I have to wipe all data from HDD and install the system again?

Thanks for help and sorry if the question was already asked - I couldn't find one similar enough, namely when the Memtest started its endless work after kernels purge.